# Items printing twice on setInterval

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval

For some reason, every `25000 MS` (25 seconds), my ListLabels are being printed out twice. These duplicates are created exactly every 25 seconds. My code is below:

```
GOT TO LABELS ________________________________
Labels:
- [Imap]/Trash
- DRAFT
- UNREAD
- CATEGORY_UPDATES
- CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS
- INBOX
- CATEGORY_SOCIAL
- CATEGORY_PERSONAL
- CATEGORY_FORUMS
- [Imap]/Drafts
- Notes
- TRASH
- CHAT
- IMPORTANT
- [Imap]/Sent
- STARRED
- SPAM
- SENT
- [Imap]/Outbox
GOT TO LABELS ________________________________
Labels:
- [Imap]/Trash
- DRAFT
- UNREAD
- CATEGORY_UPDATES
- CATEGORY_PROMOTIONS
- INBOX
- CATEGORY_SOCIAL
- CATEGORY_PERSONAL
- CATEGORY_FORUMS
- [Imap]/Drafts
- Notes
- TRASH
- CHAT
- IMPORTANT
- [Imap]/Sent
- STARRED
- SPAM
- SENT
- [Imap]/Outbox
```

This is my main JS file, it's using modules such as express, as well as some of my own modules.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var fs = require('fs');
var getnewtoken = require('./auth.js');
var getauth = require('./getauth.js');
var getnewauth = require('./getnewauth.js');
var SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/'];
var google = require('googleapis');
var googleAuth = require('google-auth-library');

// getnewtoken(function (auth) { NEW ACCESS TOKEN
// listLabels(auth);
// });


listLabels();

    function startproccess(token) {
            getauth(token, function (auth) {
                setInterval( function (){
                    listLabels(auth);
                }, 25000)
            });
    }

function listLabels(auth) {
    if(typeof auth === 'undefined'){ // First run, no auth key found
        getnewtoken( function (token) {
            startproccess(token);
        });
        console.log('auth not valid, going to startproccess');
    }
        var gmail = google.gmail('v1');
        gmail.users.labels.list({
                auth: auth,
                userId: 'me@email.com',
        }, function(err, response) {
                if (err) { // API KEY NO LONGER VALID
                        console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
                        // Get new access token
                        getnewtoken( function (token) {
                            startproccess(token);
                            console.log("New token added");
                            return;
                        });
                        return;
                }
                var labels = response.labels;
                if (labels.length == 0) {
                        console.log('No labels found.');
                } else {
                        console.log('Labels:');
                        for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
                                var label = labels[i];
                                console.log('- %s', label.name);
                        }
                }
        });
}


app.listen(3000, function(){
    //console.log("Listening on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: Well... you are calling the function twice...
Add 'return' if auth=='undefined'

Comment: Correct, you can post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once

```
auth==='undefined'
```

you need to break the function, otherwise it will keep running until the end.

In your code you are calling the function startproccess twice while it should only be called once.

Just add "return" if auth==='undefined' so the function breaks.